# drawing a set of parametric curves in 2D

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, draw, pgfmath

I want to draw some of parametric curves on the same xy-pane.
The curves are (\gamma_r(t)=(\dfrac{(r*cos t + 0.5)(0.5 r*cos t +1)-r^2*sin^2 t}{(0.5r*cos t +1)^2 +r^2*sin^2 t} , \dfrac{0.75 r*sin t}{(0.5 r*cos t +1)^2 +r^2*sin^2 t}))
for (-\pi<t<\pi) and (r=1, 1/2, 1/3 , 1/4, 1/5, 1/6 ,1/7, 1/8, 1/9).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can almost literally take your expressions and plot them. You only need to change implicit multiplications to explicit ones, `*`, add a few parentheses and in the simplest implementation change `t` and `r` to `\t` and `\r`. You also may use `pow` instead of `^` because the latter has some unexpected sign conventions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trig format=rad,scale=3,
    declare function={%
    gammarx(\r,\t)=((\r*cos(\t)+0.5)*(0.5*\r*cos(\t)+1)-pow(\r*sin(\t),2)/%
    (pow(0.5*\r*cos(\t)+1,2)+pow(\r*sin(\t),2));
    gammary(\r,\t)=(0.75*\r*sin(\t))/(pow(0.5*\r*cos(\t)+1,2)+pow(\r*sin(\t),2));}]
 \foreach \r in {1/2, 1/3 , 1/4, 1/5, 1/6 ,1/7, 1/8, 1/9}
 {\draw plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=-pi:pi] 
    ({gammarx(\r,\t)},{gammary(\r,\t)});}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`pgfplots` is specialized on such plots, so you can use e.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={%
    gammarx(\r,\t)=((\r*cos(\t)+0.5)*(0.5*\r*cos(\t)+1)-pow(\r*sin(\t),2)/%
    (pow(0.5*\r*cos(\t)+1,2)+pow(\r*sin(\t),2));
    gammary(\r,\t)=(0.75*\r*sin(\t))/(pow(0.5*\r*cos(\t)+1,2)+pow(\r*sin(\t),2));}]
 \begin{axis}[trig format plots=rad]    
 \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1/2, 1/3 , 1/4, 1/5, 1/6 ,1/7, 1/8, 1/9}
 {\addplot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=-pi:pi] 
    ({gammarx(#1,\t)},{gammary(#1,\t)});}
 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much,, amazing!

Comment: Is it actually to make every curve in a different color? or maybe just the first 3 of them?

Comment: @A.Rahman In the second example this is as easy as using `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1/2, 1/3 , 1/4, 1/5, 1/6 ,1/7, 1/8, 1/9}
 {\addplot+[smooth,variable=\t,domain=-pi:pi,no marks] 
  ({gammarx(#1,\t)},{gammary(#1,\t)});}` (and you can control the colors and line styles by playing with so-called cycle lists). In the first example you could do `\foreach \r/\color in {{1/2}/red,{1/3}/blue,{1/4}/orange,{1/5}/purple,
 {1/6}/cyan,{1/7}/magenta,{1/8}/teal,{1/9}/black}
 {\draw[color/.expanded=\color] plot[smooth,variable=\t,domain=-pi:pi] 
  ({gammarx(\r,\t)},{gammary(\r,\t)});}`.

Comment: Thanks again!  .

Comment: I actually have another question regarding this picture. Is it possible to draw another function (with different variables) so both function appear on the same plane (over each other)?

Comment: @A.Rahman Yes, you can add as many `\addplot` commands to an `axis` environment as you wish. And of course you can define a second family of functions in the same way as above.

Comment: Thanks as always!

Comment: I am sorry I am too bad in this I couldn't do them ,, I will ask a new question so if you like to answer